# View Page Source in Meteor App shows many scripts included

Tags: javascript, meteor, minify

When I left click and select view page source on my webpage it shows many many scripts included.

Is there any way where you can minify all those scripts so that all the files won't be shown seperately.

Is there any meteor command which does so?

Comment: This is only the case in development. The files are all minified and combined when you deploy.

Comment: Specifically, Meteor uses the **standard-minifiers** package for this -  [Package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/standard-minifiers)

Comment: I have deployed my app to production and facing same problem there too! :(

Comment: how did you deploy? did you use `meteor build`?

Comment: I you have deployed and have this issue try using --production flag when building your app

Comment: @PhilipPryde Its Working! thanks can you post it as answer so that i can verify your answer?

Comment: @HarshMakadia Done, cheers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have deployed manually using build and have this issue try using `--production` flag when building your app